# Getting record count of subform when filtered using acCmdFilterMenu

Tags: ms-access

I'm wanting to get a record count of my subform each time it is filtered in some way. The text box containing the record count value will be held on the main form.

The record count method I'm familiar with is:

`Trim([FORM/SUBFORM ADDRESS].RecordsetClone.RecordCount)`

This works fine where the subform is being filtered by changes to Record Source's SQL via VBA.

More recently though I've added the ability for the user to also filter on the subform columns using command buttons running `acCmdFilterMenu`, i.e. these type of menus:

[image: acCmdFilterMenu type menus]

I've put the record count method in a module so it could be called globally between form and subform events:

```vb
Public Sub InboxCount()

    Forms!Home.txtInboxCount = Trim(Forms!Home!tblJob_Search_sub.Form.RecordsetClone.RecordCount)

End Sub
```

I'm then calling the record count in the subform's OnApplyFilter event:

```vb
Private Sub Form_ApplyFilter(Cancel As Integer, ApplyType As Integer)

    MsgBox "Filter Applied"

    InboxCount

End Sub
```

The test message "Filter Applied" fires so it is running the code in that event, it just seems that the record count method I'm using doesn't work when the subform is filtered using `acCmdFilterMenu`... it does work when I filter the subform using commands that change the Record Source's SQL though.

How might I get the subform's record count when the subform is filtered using `acCmdFilterMenu`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a textbox (you can hidde it with `Visible=False`) in the footer section of the subform and set it's sourceObject to `=Count(*)`
Let's name it `txtRecordCount`.

In your parent form, create another textbox that references the previous textbox. Set the SourceObject to `=[NameOfSubformControl].Form![txtRecordCount]`

Comment: Thank you very much. This works for the `acCmdFilterMenu` method so have accepted the answer, however the textbox on the parent form reads `#Error` when the subform is filtered by changing its record source's SQL. I'm sure I can figure out how to use a different method of counting records depending on the context though.

Comment: This adds a column in the datasheet view of that form that shows 0 until it is clicked on... How unfortunate.